# RLMException after key change - already opened with different encryption key aft

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have an app that after a logout, for compliance reasons, need to erase all Realm data and change the encryption key.

It's not quite the same situation of [RLMException "Realm at path ' ' already opened with different encryption key" after writeCopy(toFile:,encryptionKey:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780841/rlmexception-realm-at-path-already-opened-with-different-encryption-key-af)

I'm deleting all files after ensuring all of the Realm objects have been deallocated.

```
+ (void)deleteRealm:(BOOL)emptyDatabase numRetries:(NSUInteger)numRetries
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AppDataStoreWillFlushDatabaseNotification" object:self];

    if (emptyDatabase)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
            [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
                [realm deleteAllObjects];
            }];
            [realm invalidate];
        }
    }

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    NSArray<NSURL *> *realmFileURLs = @[
        config.fileURL,
        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"lock"],
        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"log_a"],
        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"log_b"],
        [config.fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"note"],
        [[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.realm.management", [[config.fileURL URLByDeletingPathExtension] lastPathComponent]]]
    ];
    for (NSURL *URL in realmFileURLs)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [manager removeItemAtURL:URL error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            // handle error
            DDLogError(@"Error deleting realm file - %@", error);
        }
    }

    // Remove old password
    [CHPasswordManager wipeKeyFromSecurityEnclave];

    [self configureRealm:(numRetries + 1)];
}
```

And recreating with:

```
+ (void)configureRealm:(NSUInteger)numRetries
{
    // Setup the encryption key
    NSString *encryptionKey = [CHPasswordManager encryptedStorePassphrase];

    // If encryption key is not valid anymore, generate a new one (CoreData used a 32 chars string while Realm uses a 64 chars string)
    if (encryptionKey.length == 32)
    {
        [CHPasswordManager wipeKeyFromSecurityEnclave];
        encryptionKey = [CHPasswordManager encryptedStorePassphrase];
    }

    NSData *key = [encryptionKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

    config.encryptionKey = key;

    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];

    @autoreleasepool {
        @try {
            [RealmUser allObjects];
        }@catch (NSException *e) {
            if ([e.name isEqual:@"RLMException"])
            {
                // Something went wrong with encryption key - delete database and recreate again
                if (numRetries >= kRetriesThreshold)
                {
                    [Bugsnag notify:e];
                } else {
                    [self deleteRealm:NO numRetries:numRetries];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm often getting a RLMException:

> "reason: 'Realm at path
>   '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/152AC3D5-FD24-40DD-AFD7-5A3C4F6EE282/data/Containers/Data/Application/2F0140CF-68E4-4D0E-8AC0-BB869BEE9BF8/Documents/default.realm'
>   already opened with different encryption key'"

Funny thing is that:

> '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/152AC3D5-FD24-40DD-AFD7-5A3C4F6EE282/data/Containers/Data/Application/2F0140CF-68E4-4D0E-8AC0-BB869BEE9BF8/Documents/default.realm'

Isn't even on the filesystem.

Any hints to fix the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that `[self configureRealm:numRetries];` is getting called somewhere else outside of `[deleteRealm:(BOOL)emptyDatabase numRetries:(NSUInteger)numRetries`?

Comment: Another idea.  It seems like anytime this fails `[manager removeItemAtURL:URL error:&error];`, you'll still try to configure realm again and this would produce the error since the database still exists, wasn't deleted from disk.

Comment: No, I checked. Funny is that '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/152AC3D5-FD24-40DD-AFD7-5A3C4F6EE282/data/Containers/Data/Application/2F0140CF-68E4-4D0E-8AC0-BB869BEE9BF8/Documents/default.realm does not exist and it complains about already opened with different encryption key.

Comment: Got it. And this only occasionally happens?  Or every time?   Is there any consistent pattern on when it occurs?

Comment: @EricMaxwell I can reproduce pretty consistently.

Comment: This almost certainly means that the Realm file is still open, likely due to `RLMRealm` instances or other Realm accessor objects keeping it open.

Comment: @bdash the funny thing is that default.realm does not exist in the filesystem.

Comment: Deleting a file from disk doesn’t result in it being closed. Realm is aware that a Realm file is already open at a given path and reuses the existing file to avoid expensive file system operations each time a new reference to the Realm is retrieved.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774089/1991710, in which I discuss approaches to replacing a Realm file while your app is running.

Comment: is there a canonical way to empty a realm database and change the password?

Comment: Yes, and I outlined how in the answer I linked to. In short, you must ensure that the Realm is not open when you replace it (i.e., that you have no references to `RLMRealm` instances, or objects retrieved from them).

Comment: @bdash I'm pretty sure I don't have any reference left. I wonder if Realm has a sample on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @bdash outlined in his other issue, when a `RLMRealm` instance is created and wasn't explicitly contained in an `@autoreleasepool`, Realm internally caches references to that Realm. This is done by design in order to ensure that Realm runs as efficiently as possible.

While an obvious solution would be to simply enclose literally every Realm operation in your app in an `@autoreleasepool`, this would be detrimental to performance since you'll be then forcing Realm to open a new reference to disk each and every time you call it.

I have one potential solution that no one has mentioned directly in here: Don't recycle `default.realm`.

The problem here is that you are creating a fresh copy of `default.realm` while there are lingering references to the old Realm of the same file name still in memory.

A reasonable compromise would be that instead of recreating `default.realm`, you instead create a new Realm file with a unique file name each time you do this log-out operation, and then set that as your default Realm. For example, instead of `default.realm`, you generate a UUID string (e.g `7742e4bc-9f2b-44ae-acf1-7fb424438816.realm`), store a reference to its file name somewhere else (`NSUserDefaults` is probably fine), and use that as the filename in `RLMRealmConfiguration`.

That way, whenever you need to delete the old Realm and create a new one, the new one will be considered a wholly new entity in your app, and the remnants of cache will not interfere, and will be gone by the time the app next launches. :)